# How does the "branch-prob" flag work in llvm?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, branch

I mean the command like `opt -enable-new-pm=0 -branch-prob -analyze source_if.ll`

then the output might be:

```sh
Printing analysis 'Lazy Branch Probability Analysis' for function 'main':
---- Branch Probabilities ----
  edge entry -> for.cond probability is 0x80000000 / 0x80000000 = 100.00% [HOT edge]
  edge for.cond -> for.body probability is 0x7c000000 / 0x80000000 = 96.88% [HOT edge]
  edge for.cond -> for.end probability is 0x04000000 / 0x80000000 = 3.12%
  edge for.body -> for.inc probability is 0x40000000 / 0x80000000 = 50.00%
  edge for.body -> if.end probability is 0x40000000 / 0x80000000 = 50.00%
  edge if.end -> for.inc probability is 0x80000000 / 0x80000000 = 100.00% [HOT edge]
  edge for.inc -> for.cond probability is 0x80000000 / 0x80000000 = 100.00% [HOT edge]
```

How does it work?

My source code is

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 20000

int main(){
    float a = 0;
    float b = 0;
    float c = 0;
    float d = 0;
    float e = 0;
    int f = 10;
    int g = 5;
    for (int i = N; i > 0; i--){
        e += i;
        a += i;
        b -= i;
        c = a - b;
        if(i != N){
            continue;
        }
        printf("done\n");
        d = i/c;
        e += d * a;
        e += 1;
    }
    printf("finish.\n");
}
```

The probability of going to the line `printf("done\n");` may be `1/20000`.

I don't really know why the `-branch-prob` tell that the probability is `50%`.

This problem confuses me for a long time.

Comment: `-branch-prob` is probably for branch prediction.

Comment: Quoting the comment from the top of the file: "the branch probabilities are not computed when the analysis pass is executed but rather when the BPI results is explicitly requested by the analysis client."